# How to solve `Unknown word (CssSyntaxError)` of a variable name in `styled-jsx` (stylelint)

Tags: next.js, stylelint, css-in-js

I use *Next.js* with *styled-jsx* together with *stylelint* and everything goes well until when I start to use `variables` in *styled-jsx* because stylelint throw `stylelint(CssSyntaxError)` on those variables.

For example

```
const Button = ({ color }) => (
  <>
    <button>Hello World!</button>

    <style jsx>{`
      button {
        color: ${color || 'blue'};
                 ^^^^^ Unknown word (CssSyntaxError)
      }
    `}</style>
  </>
)
```

I don't know how to fix it or is it have any plugins that can help.

Comment: Have you tried to rename your variable to something different? customColor e.g. ?